# weekly averaged pressure data for the reclaim water system for 1 year

Tags: sql-server, database, dateadd

I have the following query built and provides the needed data, but i cannot figure out how to piece create the "Start WeekDate & End WeekDate inside the query; below is a pic of the existing query and below that is the dataset and the at the bottom is what I would like the result to look like?.....any help would be appreciated.

Query:

```sql
SELECT TOP (100) MONTH(DateTime) AS Month, 
                 { fn WEEK(DateTime) } AS week, 
                 AVG(CASE WHEN TagName = 'RCW_TierraV.Pressure_In' THEN [Value] END) AS [Tierra Verde Avg]
  FROM dbo.v_AnalogHistory
 WHERE (wwResolution = 60000) AND 
       (TagName = N'RCW_TierraV.Pressure_In') AND 
       (DateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND 
       (DateTime <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-03-31 00:00:00', 102))
  GROUP BY { fn WEEK(DateTime) }, MONTH(DateTime)
  ORDER BY Month, week
```

Query Results:

[image: query results]

I would like the final report to look like this:

[image: final report]

I changed the query as follows:

DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) - 1), getdate()-1) AS WeekStart
DATEADD(day, 7 - (DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())), getdate()) As WeekEnd

and got the following results, as you can see i'm close but the dates are all the same, how do i get the dateadd function to read through the {week} column?

```
'[latest results][3]
```

Comment: Where do the random days of the month come from in your expected results? How is the query supposed to know that year 2021, month 1, week 1 should actually start on 12/27/2020?

Comment: Please don't use images for data - use formatted text.

Comment: formatted text?

Comment: the query defines the start & end date as    "(DateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND 
       (DateTime <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-03-31 00:00:00', 102))"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) MONTH(DateTime) AS Month, 
             { fn WEEK(DateTime) } AS week, 
             AVG(CASE WHEN TagName = 'RCW_TierraV.Pressure_In' THEN [Value] END) AS [Tierra Verde Avg],
             DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(dw, DateTime) - 1), DateTime) AS WeekStart
             DATEADD(day, 7 - (DATEPART(dw, DateTime)), DateTime) As WeekEnd
  FROM dbo.v_AnalogHistory
 WHERE (wwResolution = 60000) AND 
   (TagName = N'RCW_TierraV.Pressure_In') AND 
   (DateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND 
   (DateTime <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-03-31 00:00:00', 102))
  GROUP BY { fn WEEK(DateTime) }, MONTH(DateTime)
  ORDER BY Month, week
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally got it to work, thank you for your help.